# Convolution of an $L^1$ function and a function that tends to $0$ results in a function that tends to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, convolution

I'm trying to solve the following problem in review for a test, but have only partly succeeded:

> Let $K \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ be a bounded, measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$, with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$. Let $F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x-t)f(t)\mathrm dt$. Prove that $F(x)$ is finite for every $x$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 0$.

Using Hölder's inequality it was straightfoward to show $F(x)$ finite for any $x$. Any suggestions on how one can show that $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** rewrite the integral as $$F(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}K(s)f(x-s)\mathrm ds,$$
then use a dominated convergence argument.

Comment: When I change the variable in the integral I get $F(x) = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(s) f(x-s)\mathrm ds$, is that right?

Comment: @bosmacs: No, the function is as Davide has given.  Think of the value of $F(x)$ as the integral of the product of $K$ and $f$ at points whose sum is $x$. If you think of it as a change of variables, it is
$$
-\int_\infty^{-\infty}K(s)f(x-s)\,\mathrm{d}s
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty K(s)f(x-s)\,\mathrm{d}s
$$

Comment: OK, that's clear now. However, I'm still struggling to come up with a dominating function...

Comment: Take $x\mapsto\sup |f|\cdot K(x)$.

Comment: That had occurred to me but I don't (yet) see how it helps (I'm probably overlooking something obvious). Two things: I assume we want to show $\int_{\mathbb{R}} K(s) f(x-s)ds \leq \sup|f| \cdot K(x)$, but am not sure how; in addition, what if $K$ is integrable but $K(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ (e.g. at every positive integer has a peak of height 1 with area $2^{-n}$.

Comment: The statement of the dominated convergence theorem is: if $h_n$ are measurable functions such that $|h_n(x)|\leqslant a(x)$ for some $a$ integrable and $h_n\to h$ almost everywhere, then $\int |h_n-h|\to 0$. Here, we can be reduced to sequences. We define $h_n(s):=K(s)f(x_n-s)$, where $x_n\uparrow\infty$. Then $h_n\to 0$ almost everywhere and $|h_n(s)|\leqslant |K(s)|\cdot \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|f(t)|$.